# How can I create a database window attached to a google spreadsheet?

Tags: database, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to give 80 companies the ability to give me their information for use at my work. This includes 100-200 answers, most of which are text (eg names).

I don't want to make 80 Google Sheets with protected cells (eg my instructions, my formulas), and I don't want one master spreadsheet or they will see each other's information. Google Forms is really intended for short, never-go-back-to questionnaires, but the companies may make many changes over a month or two, and I don't want them to have to retype all 100 answers. Even pre-starting a Google Form answer for each company is a lot of work.

I found ways to have a spreadsheet push to a document but not the other way around. I've searched for weeks but I am at the end of my ability to think of new keywords to use.

Comment: Given that your situation seems to demand a lot of specification from you, I think it's better if you either write your own software or go and hire a programmer to do your bidding (or stick with the spreadsheets).

Comment: You are looking at a fairly custom piece of software. Perhaps, 80 individual, single tab spreadsheets shared to each company and use importrange (using 80 importrange formulas will be slow) or scripts to pull the information from these sheets into your private sheet with all your formulas etc. You can use a very simple script to create your 80 spreadsheets too.